# Why my predictions are all zeros during the training phase of my Neural Network?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, prediction, training-data

I am a beginner with PyTorch, and I'm working on a small project which consists in predicting some output. To do this I'm using a Neural Network that has a few layers with simple transforms.

When I try to run my code I'm faced with the following problem : every prediction of my neural network is 0 (sometimes it gives other values in the first batch when I'm lucky enough...)

Here is the code of my project :

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision.transforms import Lambda, Compose

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 20      #Nombre de variables de direction résumant la variance du payoff
d = 20      #Dimension de l'option

N_data_training = 5000      #Taille de la base de donnée utile à l'apprentissage du réseau de neurones
N_data_test = 2500      #Taille de la base de donnée utile au test de la précision du réseau de neurones entrainé

type_product = "basket call"    #Type de produit dérivé
S0 = 100      #Spot price
K = 100     #Strike
T = 1     #Maturité
r = 0.05      #Taux d'intérêt sans risque
sigma = 0.2     #Volatilité
# Nmc = 1000      #Nombre de trajectoires générées pour l'estimation de Monte-Carlo
learning_rate = 1e-3

device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
print("Using {} device".format(device))

def payoff_derivative(N_data, type_product, d, S0, r, sigma, T): #### pay-offs test
  payoff = np.zeros(N_data)
  Z = np.zeros((N_data, d))

  if type_product == "basket call":
    for i in range(N_data):
      Z[i, :] = S0*np.exp((r-0.5*sigma**2)*T + sigma*np.sqrt(T)*np.random.randn(d))
      payoff[i] = np.maximum((1/d)*np.sum(Z[i, :], axis=0) - K, 0)

  return (Z, payoff)

pure_data_training = payoff_derivative(N_data_training, type_product, d, S0, r, sigma, T) ##### pay-offs pour l'apprentissage du réseau de neurones
pure_data_test = payoff_derivative(N_data_test, type_product, d, S0, r, sigma, T) ##### pay-offs pour le test de précision


class Creation_Dataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, pure_data):
    self.Z = pure_data[0]
    self.payoff = pure_data[1]

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.payoff)

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    return torch.tensor(self.Z[idx],dtype=torch.float), torch.tensor(self.payoff[idx],dtype=torch.float)


dataset_training = Creation_Dataset(pure_data_training)
dataset_test = Creation_Dataset(pure_data_test)

# Creation des data loaders
batch_size = 100
train_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset_training, batch_size)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset_test, batch_size)

for X, y in train_dataloader:
    print("Shape of X : ", X.shape, X.dtype)
    print("Shape of y: ", y.shape, y.dtype)
    print(X[0])
    print(y[0])
    break

class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self): ######méthode dans laquelle on définit les couches du réseau
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten() ########## convertit en tenseur 1D
        self.linear_relu_stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(d, n, bias=False),
            nn.Linear(n, 6),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(6, 15),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(15, 10),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(10, 5),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(5, 1),
            nn.ReLU()
          )

    def forward(self, x):
        logits = self.linear_relu_stack(x)
        return torch.reshape(logits, (-1,))

model = NeuralNetwork().to(device)
print(model)

loss_fn = nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

def train_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        # Compute prediction and loss
        print("Shape of X : ", X.shape, X.dtype)
        print("Shape of y: ", y.shape, y.dtype)
        pred = model(X)
        print(pred)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        # Backpropagation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), batch * len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")

def test(dataloader, model):
    model.eval()
    test_loss, correct = 0, 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for X, y in dataloader:
            X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
            pred = model(X)
            test_loss += loss_fn(pred, y).item()
            correct += float((pred == y).sum()) 
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    test_loss /= size
    correct /= size
    print(f"Accuracy: {100*correct:.2f}%, Avg loss (sqrt(MSE)) : {np.sqrt(test_loss):.3f} \n")

epochs = 2
for t in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {t+1}\n-------------------------------")
    train(train_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
    test(test_dataloader, model)
```

So, using a DataLoader that creates batches of batch_size, I train my Neural Network in the train_loop() function and I print out my predictions' tensor, and it turns out that all my predictions are zeros. I've seen a few topics with people facing this kind of problems with classification problems, but I'm still trying to solve it for predicting correct outputs.

Thank you for your time

Comment: what kind of dataset are you using? I believe the categories or annotations you are using for the training are not evenly balanced. once it tried to identify the images it can't find many examples returning the same result every time.

check how balanced are the sample dataset